# Summing contiguous non zero tensor values

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to find the summation of contiguous non zero tensor values as shown below

Let’s say, I have a tensor `A = [1.3, 0.0, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]`. And I want to

1) sum up the *contiguous* non-zero values of the tensor to output `[1.3, 0.0, 2.1]` and then choose the maximum which is `2.1`.

2) find the indices as well which were used to sum these values. In this case it will be `2, 3, 4`.

Comment: I'm sorry, how is `[1.3, 0.0, 2.1]` is the sum of tensor `A = [1.3, 0.0, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]`. Am I missing something?!!

Comment: Basic questions: what is `tensor` here? And what language are you using?

Comment: @YiBao `A` is a tensor here. I am using pytorch

Comment: @Anwarvic I want the output like that. It is clearly not the sum of the entire tensor but of elements. I was thinking if `map()` or `lambda()` might be helpful

Comment: @amy could you please elaborate on how this `[1.3, 0.0, 2.1]` is the sum of elements in `A`?

Comment: @amy I think you mean "tensor `A = `" instead of "`tensor A =`". And same question as Anwarvic asks.

Comment: @Anwarvic `1.3` is the first element. I do not want to proceed further for summation since the next element is `0.0` then the next element is `0.0` so I want to leave it as it is, then sum `0.6,0.7,0.8` since there is no element with value `0.0`. Hence, it is `1.3, 0.0, 2.1`

Comment: @YiBao Kindly see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is somewhat different from @Anwarvic. I try to do it in one pass. See the function below. It moves through the array and keep a log of max it has seen so far and current sum. Current sum is updated to 0 if we hit a zero or sum up the value to current if non-zero.

```
def find_continguous_max_sum(t): 
    max_,cur=0,0 
    max_indices, cur_indices = [], []

    for idx, i in enumerate(t): 
        if (i==0.0): 
            cur = 0 
            cur_indices = []
        else: 
            cur = cur+i
            cur_indices.append(idx)
        if (max_ < cur): 
            max_ = cur 
            max_indices = cur_indices 

    return max_, max_indices

#usage
find_contiguous_max_sum(A)
```

Comment: The only thing I am unable to understand is that when I have tensors and the max is made of different number of elements, so for example 2 elements for first batch, 4 elements for the second batch etc. How can I convert the list of indices back to a tensor. I will need to add padding which I don't know how to do.

Comment: @amy Not it returns the indices too

Comment: Didn't understand. Isn't it returning the list of indices. I am asking if I have to make a tensor, how will that be possible. Let's say indices are like `[4,5]` and `[1,2,3]`. I am not sure if we can directly do `torch.tensor` since the dimensions are not correct.

Comment: You can just call `torch.tensor(indices)` to get tensor indices. If you want it to be same size as original tensor you can initialize all zeros and copy this values? 
`res= torch.zeros(size);  `

Comment: I want to dynamically find the max in the batch size. Like in the previous example it would be `[4, 5, 0],[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. How did the results came out `[4,5,0]` or `[1,2,3]

Comment: I think after padding that's how it should be. The maximum length of the list is 3 but the first list's length is 2 so we pad at the end.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this problem in two simple steps:

First, split the main tensor based on the zero. So, the given tensor `A` would look like this `[ [1.3], [0], [0.6, 0.7, 0.8] ]`. This can be done using the following function:

```
def split_list(lst, value=0):
    """
    Splits a given list based on a given value
    default is zero
    """
    groups = []
    sub_group = []
    for i in lst:
        if i == 0:
            groups.append(sub_group)
            sub_group = []
            groups.append([0])
        else:
            sub_group.append(i)
    if sub_group:
        groups.append(sub_group)
    return groups
```

Second, sum each sub-group. The indices returned will be a little tricky. So, let's see it in code:

```
def get_max_indices(groups):
    """
    This function takes a list of lists and 
    returns the indices of the maximum elements
    """
    maximum = 0
    max_length = 0
    total_elements = 0
    length_before = 0
    for idx, sub_group in enumerate(groups):
        summation = sum(sub_group)
        if summation > maximum:
            maximum = summation
            max_length = len(sub_group)
            length_before = total_elements
        total_elements += len(sub_group)
    return [_ for _ in range(length_before, length_before+max_length)]
```

Now, let's try them both:

```
>>> lst = [1.3, 0, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]
>>> groups = split_list(lst, value=0)
>>> print(get_max_indices(groups))
[2, 3, 4]
```

Let's try another example:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 0, 6, 9, 0, 10]
>>> groups = split_list(lst, value=0)
>>> print(get_max_indices(groups))
[4, 5]
```

I hope this solves your questions. I know it's a little more complicated than what you may think, but this will get you started. I think this can be optimized and cleaned though, but I'll leave that to you.